# Override Process Class in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, process, parallel-processing

I am new to java and I am doing this **multithreaded** application in Java Swing.

I need to create a custom class which can spawn multiple threads and execute those threads at the same time.

Is it a good idea to use Process to spawn threads?

Since it is not possible to extend from **ProcessBuilder** class, Is there any other way to implement the **process** as a **class**?

Please share your thoughts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it a good idea to use Process to spawn threads?

No. That's designed to spawn *processes*, which are very different.

You can either create threads directly with code such as `new Thread(runnable).start()`, or use an [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) for pooling etc.

Comment: Jon, can u suggest any alternative

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you are using Multithreaded Swing application , I am not sure about exactly what you looking for but as an alternate solution you can think about using SwingWorker Threads.

For further details here is the link:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html

If it is just plane multithreading use ExecutorService in your ProcessBuilder.